# Proving by induction that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac1{2i-1}-\frac1{2i}\right)$

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction, proof-explanation

I have a homework problem to prove the following via induction:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n+i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2i-1} - \frac{1}{2i}\right) $$
The base case is true.

So far I've done the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{(k+1)+i}$$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{1}{(k+1)+(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2k +2} $$
$$s_k + a_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2k +2} + \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k}) $$
$$s_{k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (\frac{1}{2(k+1)-1} - \frac{1}{2(k+1)}) $$
$$ \frac{1}{2k +2} + \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k}) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (\frac{1}{2(k+1)-1} - \frac{1}{2(k+1)}) $$
$$ \frac{1}{2k +2} + \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k}) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (\frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{2k+2)}) $$

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to proceed from here.  Anyone have any hints or tips for search terms? Or corrections to what I've started above?

Comment: Please rectify the Left hand Side of the Proposition

Comment: Now that left side is summing $1/(n+I)$ it looks true.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

Write the left hand side as $f(n)$.

Note that $$f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

That's the key step - that $f(n+1)$ adds two terms to the right of the sum, but subtracts one term from the left.

Comment: Please forgive my lack of basic understanding; I kind of get this but am not quite sure how to use it.  Is this now used to generate $a_{k+1}$?  If this is too basic of a question, I'd appreciate any recommendations for places to read up and get smarter.

Comment: @blythe83 Have you actually tried using Thomas' advice? If you use it, and then apply a little elbow grease (i.e., do some basic algebraic manipulation), then your desired identity "pops right out."

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Sorry, I'm not really familiar about where the functions fit into the sums based on my work so far.  I can work with the fractions once I have them lined up like you do, I'm just still trying to learn the mechanics of getting there and why it works that way.

Comment: Let the RHS be g(n). Observe that g(n+1)-g(n)=1/(2n+1)-1/(2n+2).  For the induction to work, this should be equal to f(n+1)-f(n).

Comment: Thanks @user254665!  This finally made it click for me; for some reason I wasn't processing that I was writing both sides as a function.  I was able to solve it from there.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Andrews notes, the key part lies in reindexing the sum (so you can apply the inductive hypothesis, IH). More explicitly, the following is the core part of the inductive argument:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{k+1+i}&=\sum_{i=2}^{k+2}\frac{1}{k+i}\tag{reindex}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{k+i}+\frac{1}{2k+2}+\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\tag{rewrite}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=1}^k\left(\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i}\right)+\frac{1}{2k+2}+\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\tag{IH}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=1}^k\left(\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+2}\right)\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i}\right).\tag{rewrite}
\end{align}

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Thanks, this is starting to make sense.  I didn't know about re-indexing, that's pretty neat!  The only thing I don't understand is how you go from that re-indexed sum using $\sum_{i=2}^{k+2}$ to it using $\sum_{i=1}^{k}$

Comment: @blythe83 Thomas' answer gives the verbal description (mine provides the algebra): "adds two terms to the right of the sum but subtracts one term from the left." Which two terms do you see that are being added? What $i$-values do these terms correspond to? Ask yourself the same question for the term that is being subtracted.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to step away for a minute and see if clearing my head makes me understand what you're saying a little better.  Appreciate you walking me through it!